# Concatenation of multiple rows into one string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, string-concatenation

This is my first question asked here at stackoverflow, so bear with me please :)

I asked it in another thread as it was related to that question, but was directed to ask in a new question thread so here it is.

I have a table with note-texts with each line holding a max of 256 characters, these are sequenced by a field "linenumber" but I am not sure that the order of linenumber in the database is in sequence. How would I re-design this query to ensure sequencing by linenumber for each notesrecid?

On the table NOTES_V there is a field called "linenumber" - I tried ordering the BA aliased by notesrecid then linenumber, but ordering is not allowed within a subquery.

I realize that the outcome in extreme and highly unlikely cases may overflow 8000 characters of varchar, but is that a problem or will it "just" be truncated to the 8000 character max?

```
SELECT A.DATASET, A.NOTESRECID, LEFT(A.NOTETXT,LEN(A.NOTETXT)-2) AS "NOTETXT", LEN(A.NOTETXT)-2 AS "#CHARS"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT BB.DATASET, BB.NOTESRECID,
        (SELECT BA.TXT+', ' AS [text()]
         FROM NOTES_V BA
         WHERE BA.DATASET=BB.DATASET AND BA.NOTESRECID=BB.NOTESRECID
         ORDER BY BA.DATASET, BA.NOTESRECID
         FOR XML PATH (''))  [NOTETXT]
  FROM NOTES_V BB) A
```

The method written below works great, but I ran into a problem with CHAR(7) not being serializable, so my slightly re-written query is below replacing CHAR(7) with a blank space.

```
SELECT A.DATASET, A.NOTESRECID, A.NOTETXT, LEN(A.NOTETXT) AS "#CHARS"
FROM (SELECT BB.DATASET, BB.NOTESRECID,
      stuff((SELECT REPLACE(BA.TXT,CHAR(7),' ')+', ' AS [text()]
             FROM NOTES_V BA
             WHERE BA.DATASET=BB.DATASET AND BA.NOTESRECID=BB.NOTESRECID
             ORDER BY BA.DATASET, BA.NOTESRECID, BA.linenumber
             FOR XML PATH ('A'),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') [NOTETXT]
             FROM NOTES_V BB
             GROUP BY BB.DATASET, BB.NOTESRECID) A
```

Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: In SQL 2008 you could use varchar(max). It has no character limit.

Comment: You mention that you have tried ordering by notesrecid, but nothing about what this column is. Could you please add table structure with some explanation of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.DATASET, A.NOTESRECID, A.NOTETXT, LEN(A.NOTETXT) AS "#CHARS"
FROM (SELECT BB.DATASET, BB.NOTESRECID,
        stuff((SELECT BA.TXT+', ' AS [text()]
         FROM NOTES_V BA
         WHERE BA.DATASET=BB.DATASET AND BA.NOTESRECID=BB.NOTESRECID
         ORDER BY BA.DATASET, BA.NOTESRECID, BA.linenumber
         FOR XML PATH ('A'),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') [NOTETXT]
  FROM NOTES_V BB
  GROUP BY BB.DATASET, BB.NOTESRECID) A
```

Notes:

- STUFF is faster than LEFT or SUBSTRING
- If your NOTES_V.TXT data contains characters that will become XML entities, you will get some unexpected text. Using `FOR XML, TYPE` and extracting the value from it ensures this does not happen
- I prefer GROUP BY because it preceeds DISTINCT in terms of logical flow

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it. However, I am getting an error returned: "FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'text()' because it contains a character (0x0007) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive." - I am not sure how to proceed around this error - any ideas?